# Run .exe with extra parameters as windows service with sc create

Tags: service, command-prompt, arelle

I'm trying run following in my command prompt:

`sc create mynewservice  binpath="C:\Program Files\Arelle\arelleCmdLine.exe" --webserver localhost:10100`

This won't succeed since there is the `:` in the optionname.

I can't seem to find the correct syntaxt

Comment: is --webserver a switch of SC?  I can't see it in Win 8.

Comment: it's a parameter of arelleCmdLine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
sc create mynewservice binpath="C:\Program Files\Arelle\arelleCmdLine.exe --webserver localhost:10100"
```

Comment: @JMan  What do you mean?  Did you check your services panel for **mynewservice**?

Comment: I don't see the arguments in services with this approach